# discord bot python invalid syntax

Tags: python, discord.py

i am working on a python bot but i've come across a syntax error with ELIF and IF statements, and ive tried fiddling around changing the elif around, and adding an else instead n such, but i can't get it to work, so that's why i come on here to see if anyone has a solution for my problem, thanks.

My code:

```
@bot.command()
async def linkdiscord(ctx, token):

            author = ctx.message.author
            author2 = str(ctx.message.author)
            discordid = ctx.message.author.id
            response = json.loads(requests.get(forumurl + f"/api?action=linkdiscord&key=SECRET&token={token}&discordid={discordid}").text)

            if response["status"] == 200:
                embed=discord.Embed(title="Linker System",  color=0xcd65f0)
                embed.add_field(name="Linked Discord", value="Yes", inline=True)
                embed.set_footer(text="Successfully linked " + author2 + " to forum account: " + response["username"])
            elif response["status"] == 400:
                embed=discord.Embed(title="Linker System", color=0xff0000)
                embed.add_field(name="Unexpected error", value="True", inline=True)
                embed.add_field(name="Message", value= response["message"], inline=True)
                embed.set_footer(text="Error")

            
            
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            await ctx.message.delete()

            
            elif response["status"] == 420:
                server_id = 741131311467516961
                server = client.get_guild(server_id)
                member = server.get_member(ctx.message.author.id)
                await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=response["reason"])
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Python scope is determined by whitespace; The `await` calls should be in the `elif` scope.

Also, it's considered best practice to use 4 spaces for each indent. See PEP8 for more details.

```py
@bot.command()
async def linkdiscord(ctx, token):
    author = ctx.message.author
    author2 = str(ctx.message.author)
    discordid = ctx.message.author.id
    response = json.loads(requests.get(forumurl + f"/api?action=linkdiscord&key=SECRET&token={token}&discordid={discordid}").text)

    if response["status"] == 200:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Linker System",  color=0xcd65f0)
        embed.add_field(name="Linked Discord", value="Yes", inline=True)
        embed.set_footer(text="Successfully linked " + author2 + " to forum account: " + response["username"])
    elif response["status"] == 400:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Linker System", color=0xff0000)
        embed.add_field(name="Unexpected error", value="True", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Message", value= response["message"], inline=True)
        embed.set_footer(text="Error")
         
        await ctx.send(embed=embed) # Now I'm in the correct scope!
        await ctx.message.delete() # Me too!
            
    elif response["status"] == 420:
        server_id = 741131311467516961
        server = client.get_guild(server_id)
        member = server.get_member(ctx.message.author.id)
        await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=response["reason"])
```

Comment: Thanks worked! But having some issues "get_member has no attribute" (I swapped client.get_guild" to "bot.get_guild" cuz i use bot.command not client.command etc.)

Comment: Instead of `member = server.get_member(ctx.message.author.id)`, do `user = bot.fetch_user(ctx.author.id)`. Then, do `await ctx.guild.ban(user, reason=response["reason"])`.